# Streaming HTML5 Video chunks via multiple HTTP/2 TCP sockets

Tags: html, html5-video, http2

I'm trying to optimize the load time of a html5 video. Is there any way to make a browser deal with each webm video chunk as single TCP streams, to utilize HTTP/2 improved parallelisation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not directly configure whether a browser reuses the same HTTP/2 connection for making another request or whether it uses a new connection. That is up to the browser to decide.

In theory just using one HTTP/2 connection should give you optimal performance, since it avoids the overhead for having to open new connections. In practice it might be sometimes worse than using multiple HTTP/1.1 connections, due to suboptimal flow-control windows or stream priorization in some HTTP/2 implementations.

One workaround to force multiple connections might be to serve some of the chunks through a different URL (pointing towards the same server), which prevents the browser from reusing the connection. That will however require some additional effort to set it up.

Another option could be to try disabling HTTP/2 for the server which serves those chunks.

Comment: Just to mention that browsers try really hard to open as few connections as possible. A common optimization is that even with 2 different domains, if the certificate are the same and the IP is the same, then the same connection is reused. https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2016/08/18/http2-connection-coalescing/